# Dynamic survey application logic PHP/MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server, sas, survey

Firstly I think this question can be related to any language, but I specified what I was using.

Excuse me if I start to bore also, but I am trying to find out the best way to build a dynamic survey management system.
My client basically has said to me that the data has to be stored in MS SQL as his client has only got MS SQL connector for SAS, which is going to do reporting.

My logic so far is this:
1st. Setup the survey itself, i.e. ask for title, quick overview, etc, etc.
2nd. Define your questions.
3rd. Publish survey.

Now what I have done so far is that when they "publish survey", I have created a dedicated database table for this survey which will house the responses. 
From the admin side of this, they will not be able to modify the questions, maybe the question title but that is about it. They cant add/remove questions.

Question is, is creating individual database tables a good thing? My only worry really is that say the admin creates like 30 questions, I will have 30 columns in that dedicated table. To go with that, this way might be easy for the SAS system to pull in data for reporting. The administrator will not see the survey responses in the admin panel btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done something similar for a language grading exam. I opted for a more flexible approach with the following tables

```
+------+    +-------------+    +-------------+    +-------------+    +----------+
| Exam |    | Question    |    | Choice      |    | Answer      |    | User     |
+------+    +-------------+    +-------------+    +-------------+    +----------+
| id   |    | id          |    | id          |    | id          |    | id       |
| name |    | questionNb  |    | choice      |    | user_id     |    | name     |
+------+    | question    |    | question_id |    | exam_id     |    | email    |
            | exam_id     |    | isAnswer    |    | question_id |    | password |
            +-------------+    +-------------+    | choice_id   |    +----------+
                                                  | isGood      | 
                                                  +-------------+
```

This model allowed me to easilly have a 15 questions exam, a 30 questions exam and a 50 questions exam. To adapt this model for survey, you might just have to remove the isAnswer and isGood part and you should be good and replace users data with anonymous general data like age, income, sex.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a column for each question is totally wrong, altering the database at runtime for business oriented purpose is a "never ever do".
Read something about "relational databases" things should look like this:

table_surveys
id
survey_name

table_questions
id
fk_survey (foreign key to table_surveys)
question_text
(question value? maybe)

table_questions_options
id
question_id(foreign key to table_questions)
option_value (this can be true/false for a test or a numeric value  for a survey)
option_label

table_users
id
username
pass
name

table_answers
id
options_fk (foreign key to table_question_options)
users_fk (foreign key to table_users)

This way everything is linked together (No reusing of options,or questions or stuff into different surveys)

Comment: I understand what Jeff and you are saying, and to be fair top of my head I would have created a table to store all the questions answered, but because of this SAS system, I thought this would be a good option. I am not really wanting to create multiple tables and generally never code like this, I really wanted other peoples opinion on it :-)

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments in the documentation, [MS SQL Support](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php) in PHP is iffy at best.  Is PHP the only language you are allowed to use for the project?  If not, you might want to consider using C#, VB.Net or something more compatible with SQL Server.  Otherwise, you could initially store the data in MySQL, and export it to MS SQL Server when you needed to do analysis.

Comment: I was asking the client to use MYSQL but apparantly his client has purchased connector for MSSQL. Dont get me wrong, I am not a big fan of PHP/MSSQL either :-(. I might look into MYSQL then exporting out into MSSQL, but depends on how often SAS will be doing its magic

Answer (score 0):

Dont know, if I really understand your question. But I once built such a survey system. And it came out pretty quick and easy with about the following tables (if I remember right):

```
USER, SURVEYS, QUESTIONS, ANSWERS, [some mapping tables]
```

The SAS will fetch the data from virtual any table. If everything in one or two tables, it will even be easier.

Answer (score 0):

With all due respect to Kibbee, PHP/MSSQL support is actually VERY good. We do it quite often, and the performance bests PHP/MySQL and matches compiled C#/MSSQL (in our very limited and unscientific testing). This is assuming you're running PHP on a Win machine. Running PHP with a TLS connector to a separate MSSQL box is another ball of wax and can be a pain to configure.

Anyway, we had a similar scenario and went with one table to manage forms (Forms w/ FormID as the primary), another to manage fields/questions (Fields w/FieldID, FieldType such as Y/N, text, select, etc.), and another to "assign" a field to a form (FormFields w/ FormFieldID, FormID, FieldID, parameters in an array for select items, etc.). Then yet another set of tables to deal with the answering of the questions.

I agree with the rest of the group. Make sure to normalize and don't create a separate column for each question. It'll be more work initially, but you'll appreciate it when you simply have to add a few rows to a table instead of re-writing your queries and re-designing your tables.

Comment: And apologies guys for responding six months after the question was posted! My bad.